# Simple Groovy replace using regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I've been reading through regex and I thought this would work but it doesn't seem to want to work. All I need to do is strip the leading 1 off a phone number if it exists.

So:

```
def mphone = 1+555-555-5555
mphone.replace(/^1/, "")
```

Shouldn't this output +555-555-5555?

Comment: You meant `def mphone = "1+555-555-5555"` (with quotes)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I recognize two errors in your code. First one is probably a typo: you are not surrounding the phone number with quotation marks so it's an integer: 1 + 555 - 555 - 5555 = -5554

Also, you should use `replaceFirst` since there's no method `replace` in String taking a Pattern as first parameter. This works:

```
def mphone = "1+555-555-5555"
result = mphone.replaceFirst(/^1/, "")
```

Comment: Good answer. One caveat, don't forget Strings are immutable. Make sure to reassign mphone: `mphone = mphone.replaceFirst(/^1/, "")`

Comment: @Johnathon great comment, using the last line as a return value would do but I didn't think it could also be a mistaken *in-place* replacement

Comment: String contains replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) method

Answer (score 44):

`replace` is a java Method of Java's String, which replace a character with another:

```
assert "1+555-551-5551".replace('1', ' ') == " +555-55 -555 "
```

What you are looking for is `replaceAll`, which would replace all occurrences of a regex, or `replaceFirst`, that would replace the first occurrence only:

```
assert "1+555-551-5551".replaceAll(/1/, "") == "+555-55-555"
assert "1+555-551-5551".replaceFirst(/1/, "") == "+555-551-5551"
```

The `^` in your regex means that the one must be at the beginning:

```
assert "1+555-551-5551".replaceAll(/^1/, "") == "+555-551-5551"
```

so the code you posted was almost correct.